# Is it possible to compile Objective-C on a windows computer, but for mac

Tags: objective-c, windows, macos, compilation

I'm not entirely sure about mac or anything, but what I want to do, is compile my objective-c program, for a mac, but compile it on a windows computer.

Is it possible to do this?

I have already successfully compiled an Objective-C program for windows on windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compilation isn't the problem.  Linking is.

You'll need something that can spit mach-o executables.

I'm not aware of an app that can specifically target OS X, but the existence of multiple tool chains that can produce iOS binaries on Windows.  They typically require a Mac to do the signing for iOS, but that step is optional when targeting OS X.

Comment: Is it possible to "linking" like you said, but on a windows?

Comment: I think the linker is part of the llvm open source these days and the mach-o file format is well documented.   So, yes, it is possible, but might require a fairly monumental porting effort on your part.

Comment: I'm not too good with mac, so could you give me some pointers on what I should google, or where to start? ( "pointer" pun intended )

Comment: I'd start with llvm.org.